# Change value of textblock when an attribute is updated

Tags: wpf

I have a textblock in a user control and I want to set the text to the value of an attribute in a class.
Is it possible to change this value when the attribute is changed from a different user control?

In UserControl1

```
public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Block.Text = SetsTest.text;
        }
```

The class

```
public static class SetsTest
    {
        public static string text = "hello";
    }
```

In UserControl2

```
SetsTest.text = "Different Text";
//I want to change the text in "Block" now## Heading ##
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both controls must share the same `DataContext` as they are supposed to share the same data. You usually use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview) to update the view (e.g., a `TextBlock`) with data.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string sharedText;
  public string SharedText
  {
    get => this.sharedText; 
    set
    {
      this.sharedText = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }     

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
  }
}
```

**UserControl1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{    
  // Since the DataContext is inherited from the parent control (in this case the Window) 
  // you can access the view model directly by casting the DataContext to the appropriate type
  private void ChangeTextBlockText
  {
    (this.DataContext as ViewModel).SharedText = "Text  from UserControl1";
  }
}
```

**UserControl1.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyControl">

  <!-- Bind the TextBlock to the DataContext which is the ViewModel instance
    inherited from the parent element 
  -->
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding SharedText}" />
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl2.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
  // Since the DataContext is inherited from the parent control (in this case the Window) 
  // you can access the view model directly by casting the DataContext to the appropriate type    
  private void ChangeTextBlockText
  {
    // Updating the shared ViewModel instance will update the binding of
    // the UserControl1's TextBlock as it binds to the same ViewModel instance (DataContext).
    // Therefore the content of the TextBlock will change to "Text  from UserControl2"
    (this.DataContext as ViewModel).SharedText = "Text  from UserControl2";
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <!-- Since the DataContext is inherited (from Window element)
      the DataContext of both UserControl elements is still the ViewModel class 
    -->
    <UserControl1 />
    <UserControl2 />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to read about binding, is mean to solve this problems.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm

You can do this on any class but for the sake of simplicity we will do it on the codebehind of your window/usercontrol/whatever

So the first thing first, you need to tell your control to track the property you want.

```
<Textblock Text={Binding PropertyToUpdate}/>
```

After this, you get to the part when you change the property your control is tracking. In this case it will be something like this:

```
PropertyToUpdate = "new Text";
```

The property is updated but if you do this nothing will change. That is because you have to tell your view that the value of the property that is tracking has changed. To do this, you need to set the DataContext with the class that has your property, and then Notify your view. One way to do this is setting it on the constructor

```
    public MainWindow(){
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = this; //I use 'this' because the property is in the same class
}
```

and the to Notify you need your class to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

```
public class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

and then implement your way to Notify. Here is the snippet I use.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
}
```

And finally on the setter of your property, call OnPropertyChanged

```
private string _propertyToUpdate;
public string PropertyToUpdate
{
    get{ return _propertyToUpdate; }
    set
    {
        _propertyToUpdate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a delegate / event on your SetsTest class to notify clients of changes to property values:

```
public static class SetsTest
    {
        //custom event  
        public static event SetTextChangeHandler TextChange;


        private static string _text;

        public static string Text
        {
            get => _text;
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                TextChange?.Invoke();
            }   
        }
    }
```

In UserControl 1 you'd set the event to a handler:

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetsTest.TextChange += SetsTest_textChange;

    }
```

Where SetsTest_textChange is:

```
private static void SetsTest_textChange()
{
   Block.Text = SetsTest.text;         
}
```

In UserControl 2 you'd set the property:

```
SetsTest.Text = "Different Text";
```

Anytime the Text property is changed, your handler in UserControl1 will be invoked.